# MVC4 - Not executing the scripts js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to load the scripts for my application. Do not work so I checked a simple `alert ('test11');`. It also does not work, the script is not loaded at all?
It uses standard *_Layout* of MVC4 generated by Visual Studio 2013.

View **Details.cshtml**

```
@model xzy.Models.Album

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Store", FormMethod.Post,
    new
    {
        id = "someID",
        data_oneAction = @Url.Action("one"),
        data_twoAction = @Url.Action("two")
    }))
{
    <fieldset

        <label for="Formats">Select format</label>

        @Html.DropDownList("Formats", ViewBag.Formats as SelectList,
  new { id = "FormatsID", @class = "xxx" })


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" } />

    </fieldset>
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/first_file.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/second_file.js")"></script>
```

Script **first_file.js**

```
$(function () {

    $('#FormatsID').change(function () {
        alert('Test11');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Yaakov Ellis, it works. But when I have a script with the update, then it not works.

```
$(function () {

    $('#FormatsID').change(function () {
        alert('Test11');
        var URL = $('#someID').data('oneAction');
        $.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#FormatsID').val(), function (data) {
            alert('Test22');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you look at the source code for the page, does it show the script being loaded?

Comment: shows that it has been loaded. But it not works. When I add it `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` before the `<script src ...` then it works.

Comment: So now you are asking a completely different question - why a specific piece of jQuery doesn't work. Perhaps this should be asked in a new question, since the original issue in this one has been answered. And when asking, it might be helpful to include the html that is produced by your page, what is included in `#FormatsID`, what errors if any come up in the console logs, what you get when you set javascript breakpoints and step through the code, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `first_file.js` is dependent on the presence of jQuery. I suspect that if you check your console log, you will see errors on the first line of this file.

This is confirmed by the fact that when you add in a jQuery reference prior to this file (as you wrote [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350432/mvc4-not-executing-the-scripts-js?noredirect=1#comment37648667_24350432)), it works.

So if you want to use this script as-is, be sure to include jQuery first.

If you just want a better test of the `first_file.js` file, then remove all of the jQuery stuff from it. Its sole contents should be one line with `alert('Test11');` on it.